# How to send data to cloud from arduino uno?

Tags: arduino, cloud, sensors, robotics, arduino-uno

I have some sensors connected to my ardunio uno and get periodically data from that sensors now I wanted to send that data to cloud.
I dont have any idea about how should I connect my arduino to Internet using GSM. How should I solve this problem or any alternative is there.

Answer (score 0):

Just get an appropriate shield (like [this one](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield)) and follow the [documents](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield) included with it.  The linked shield includes some basic service plan as part of the purchase.  Once connected, it's just like using any other TCP/IP application.

Comment: thank you sir I try it and if stuck with any problem then reply to you